# Calculator program issue in C

Tags: c, function, calculator

I'm writing a statistical calculator, with 3 different calculation options. The problem is whenever I choose the 2nd option, it wants to print both the answer from the 1st option and the 2nd option. When I choose the 3 option, it just prints the answer the the 3rd option(the wrong answer, but thats probably a mishap in the formula). Here is the results:

```
Please Enter a number of inputs
3
Please enter number 1
1
Please enter number 2
2
Please enter number 3
3
Statistical Calculator Menu
(1) Mean
(2) Standard Deviation
(3) Range
(4) Restart/Exit
2
Here is the Mean 2.0Standard Devition is 0.8
```

Now I thought it might be an issue with how I'm calling each function, but the best I can tell thats not the case. Then I thought it might be a value that I didn't initialize, but it seems as though thats not it either. I just need another pair of eyes to see where I went wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int MAX_DATA=8;
void menu(float numbers[], int amount);
float mean(float numbers[],int amount);
float standard_dev(float numbers[], int amount);
float range( float numbers[], int amount);

int main()
{
    int i=0, amount=0;
    float numbers[MAX_DATA];
    printf("Please Enter a number of inputs \n");
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    if (amount>MAX_DATA)
    {
        printf("You entered too many numbers");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
        {
            printf("Please enter number %d\n", i+1);
            scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
        }
        menu(numbers,amount);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
void menu(float numbers[],int amount)
{
    int input2=0;
    printf("Statistical Calculator Menu");
    printf("\n(1) Mean\n(2) Standard Deviation\n(3) Range\n(4) Restart/Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&input2);
    if(input2==1)
    {
        mean(numbers,amount);
    }
    if  (input2==2)
    {
        standard_dev(numbers,amount);
    }
    if (input2==3)
    {
        range(numbers,amount);
    }
}
float mean(float numbers[],int amount)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0;
    float average=0;
    for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        sum=sum+numbers[i];
    }
    average=sum/amount;
    printf("Here is the Mean %.1f", average);
    return average;
}
float standard_dev(float numbers[], int amount)
{
    float sdev=0,dev=0,sumsqr=0,variance=0;
    int i;
    float mean2=0;
    mean2=mean(numbers,amount);
    for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        dev=numbers[i]-mean2;
        sumsqr+=dev*dev;
    }
    variance=sumsqr/(float)amount;
    sdev=sqrt(variance);
    printf("Standard Devition is %.1f", sdev);
    return sdev;
}
float range(float numbers[],int amount)
{
    int i;
    float diff=0;
    for (i=0; i<=amount; i++)
    {
        diff=numbers[amount]-numbers[1];
    }
    printf("%f\n",diff);
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: At least, try to format your wall of code next time?

Comment: If you want to know why some output got printed, look to see what function prints it and where that function is called.

Comment: By the way, checked your questions. You should at least try searching over first 3 pages of Google before you ask a question here.. Most of them seem like you're just too lazy to solve them yourself :/ No offense man, just for the sake of community! :)

Comment: I'll admit the 2 questions I asked today may have been found by searching through google, but the other ones have all been issues that I was not able to figure out through googling. I just starting to get my feet wet with this stuff, and this site is such a great resource, because you get such quick and great feedback from people such as yourself. It's really hard not to turn to this community for help. My apologies.

Comment: No problems man! Just saying, it always feels great to solve something that you feel easy by yourself even if you see that you need to work much harder than if you asked something and got the answer in two minutes :) Good luck and may the help be with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float standard_dev(float numbers[], int amount)
{
 float sdev=0,dev=0,sumsqr=0,variance=0;
 int i;
 float mean2=0;
 mean2=mean(numbers,amount); // Here it is.
```

It calls the `mean` function, which actually prints something :) You can add boolean flag `shouldPrint` to functions and pass it as `true` when you want to print it.

Also, this problem is easily solvable with simple debugging your code...if actually looking at it doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Wow! the funny part about that is, I originally just had the stand_deviation function doing a mean calculation on its own, but then changed it to call the mean function in hopes of correcting an issue I had earlier. I feel like a ratard! thank you.